# Generic throws clause handling in case of overridden methods

Tags: java, generics, exception, jls, throws

Consider the following clause from JLS: 8.4.8.3.

> If the unerased throws clause of m1 does not contain a supertype of each exception type in the throws clause of m2 (adapted, if necessary, to the type parameters of m1), a compile-time unchecked warning occurs.

Clearly - based on the other rules:

1. the super class method must throw **super-type of all exception types** that the **overridden class method throws**.
2. The child exception list cannot have more members than parent.

What can be the example that satisfies the above clause - that **leads to unchecked warning** - because based on the rules - it will outright **lead to Compile time Error**.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you think the quote means? i.e. the code that "will outright lead to Compile time Error".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
class Superclass<T extends Exception> {
    public void foo() throws T {}
}

class Subclass<T extends Exception> extends Superclass<T> {
    public void foo() throws Exception {}
}
```

`T` is not a supertype of `Exception`, so according to the quote, there should be a warning.

`Subclass.foo` actually fulfils the requirements for overriding (see [8.4.8.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1)). Specifically, `Subclass.foo` has the same signature as the erasure of the inherited `Superclass.foo`. The inherited method is supposed to throw `T`, but after erasure, it throws `Exception` too.

IntelliJ puts a red underline this, as if it were an error, but you can actually still compile and run the code.

Here is what `javac` produces:

```
% javac -J-Duser.language=en -Xlint:unchecked Superclass.java
Superclass.java:6: warning: [unchecked] foo() in Subclass cannot override foo() in Superclass
    public void foo() throws Exception {}
                ^
  overridden method does not throw Exception
1 warning
```

Comment: Had something similar in mind - but looks like Intellij fooled me :)